# SQL Query to Aggregate Growing Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a query to create a `view` which needs to contain aggregated sales data for customers but new sales data is added as columns instead of rows.  In the table, each row represents a `customer ID` and columns are "`week of 20160808`".  Is there a way to create the query to `dynamically` capture the new columns added without hard coding the column names (`20160801+20160808+20160815`)?

Comment: Besides the **ugliness** of dynamic column creation, you may consider dynamic SQL.

Comment: but `dynamic sql` does not work in a `view`

Comment: Does it have to be a view? what about a stored procedure or function? But seriously high priority - this is about the worst possible table design and it will give you no end of problems

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
SELECT Year(DateOfSale), CustomerId, [1] ... [52] FROM YourDataTable 
Pivot(sum(sales) FOR WeekNumber IN (1..52)) as Pivoted
```

It won't give you the best named columns, but you could tidy that up when you display it.